# double backslash (\\) in file name while opening

Tags: python, file

```
path = r'C:\Myfolder\data\today'
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):

    for filename in filenames:
        fname = os.path.join(root,filename)
        if os.path.isfile(fname) and fname[-4:] == '.log':
            if fname not in rows1:
               print fname
               fname=fname.replace(path,"")
               with open(fname, 'r') as myfile:
```

My file name looks like C:\Myfolder\data\today\00.log and I just need "today\00.log"
The error is IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\today\00.log'
How to remove \ from the file name?

Comment: Why are you removing the path? you could use `fname=fname.replace(path,"").lstrip("\\")` but I don't know why you are doing what you are.

Comment: why not get rid of the \ in the name. Also path = r"C:\\Myfolder\data\today"

Comment: The result is again today\\00.log - I need to store this filename in a Database table and for that I don't need absolute path.

Comment: The result was `\today\00.log` in your question so `today\\00.log` is not the same.

Comment: How are you getting `today\00.log`? `today` is in `path`, so it should be removed by `replace()`, and the result should just be `\00.log`.

Comment: Hi Padriac.. The result in the console has "\\" (double backslash), but I need single backslash (\) in the file name.

Comment: @Prasad, yes because that is the repr output, do you see two when you `print(fname)`?

Comment: No.. I see today\00.log (single backslash) - however, with open(fname, 'r') as myfile: is giving me an error (No such file or directory \Test\\00.log)

Comment: Yes, because your cwd is probably not  where Test is and you still have a leading slash in `\Test\\00.log`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Besides, there isn't really an error, you should not use replace to strip off a known prefix, use string-slicing instead and use the full filename to open the file:

```
path = r'C:\Myfolder\data\today'
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullname = os.path.join(root,filename)
        if os.path.isfile(fullname) and fullname[-4:] == '.log':
            if fullname not in rows1:
               print fullname
               fname = fullname[len(path)+1:]
               with open(fullname, 'r') as myfile:
                   do_something
```